# Which exceptions besides OSError can subprocess.Popen() raise?

Tags: python, exception, popen

In (this section)[https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#exceptions] about exceptions with subprocess.Popen the documentation says that "The most common exception raised is OSError".

Are there other, undocumented Exceptions that might by raised that are not of type OSError and are not due to invalid arguments?

I am asking this because I have the following code:

```
try:
    obj = subprocess.Popen(*args)
    #....
except OSError as e:
    pass
```

and I want this to be 100% exception free. The system I am working on is Debian GNU/Linux 7.7 (wheezy).

I not only ask this for a safe way to write my program but also out of curiousity for the python `os.Popen` implementation. So please be a bit more specific than just saying to catch `Exception`.

Comment: `ValueError` is also raised if `Popen` is called with invalid argument

Comment: If you were on windows you might run the risk of an `AssertionError` if you tried to set `pass_fds`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just catch `Exception`, if you want to be very sure you're catching everything.  That still won't catch things like `SystemExit`, but most of the time you don't want to catch those anyway.

Comment: Hm, I'm still interested what other Error can be thrown when... kinda curious

Comment: @WorldSEnder: That is an implementation detail.  Contractually, any exception may be raised at any time, unless the documentation promises otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

this will covers most of it:

```
try:
    obj = subprocess.Popen(*args)
    #....
except OSError as e:       # to catch OSError
    print e
    pass
except ValueError as e:    # to catch ValueError  
    print e
    pass
except:pass                # others
```